# Pattern recognition in binary numbers (pseudo code or MQL5)

Tags: pseudocode, mql5

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17 
.  .  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

Recognition starts at 17 and goes backwards to 0.
What can be seen is the most simple pattern.

1. Pattern starts with at least three 0s or three 1s but could be more of each but not mixed!
2. First pattern is then followed by at least five 0s or five 1s depending on what came in the first pattern. Since pattern one contains three 0, there must be at least five 1s and vice versa
3. Then we want to see the first pattern again. At least three 0s or three 1s, again, depending wheather there were 1s or 0s before
4. Finally we want to see the second pattern again, which means at least five 0s or five 1s, again, depending on which pattern was seen before

I tried using for loops and counters but did not manage to work it out. What is struggling me is the fact, that the pattern is not of fixed size as there can be more than three or five 0s and 1s in succession.

Is anybody able to provide some pseudo code how to implement this or even some MQL5 code?

Comment: If you "want to see the first pattern again", does this mean it must have the same number of 0's of 1's like 1st time, or just "at least three 0s or three 1s", independent of how much there were the 1st time (the 2nd pattern analogously).

Comment: hello! thanks for your question. Just "at least three or more" so e.g. 17 to 15 could be 0 0 0 then 1 1 1 1 1 then 0 0 0 0 0 then 1 1 1 1 1

Answer (score 0):

The following Swift code is everything else than optimal. It should just give you hints how you could implement it.

A function to match a single pattern:

```
func matchPattern(numbers: [Int], startIndex: Int, number: Int) -> Int {
    var actualIndex = startIndex
    while numbers[actualIndex] == number && actualIndex > 0 {
        actualIndex = actualIndex - 1
    }
    return startIndex - actualIndex
}
```

A function to match the 4 patterns:

```
        func match(binNrs: [Int]) -> Bool {
            let firstPatternNr = binNrs[17]
            let secondPatternNr = firstPatternNr == 0 ? 1 : 0
            let pattern1Length = matchPattern(numbers: binNrs, 
                                             startIndex: 17, 
                                             number: firstPatternNr)
            if pattern1Length < 3 { return false }
            let pattern2Length = matchPattern(numbers: binNrs, 
                                              startIndex: 17 - pattern1Length, 
                                              number: secondPatternNr)
            if pattern2Length < 5 { return false }
            let pattern3Length = matchPattern(numbers: binNrs, 
                                              startIndex: 17 - pattern1Length - pattern2Length,
                                              number: firstPatternNr)
            if pattern3Length < 3 { return false }
            let pattern4Length = matchPattern(numbers: binNrs, 
                                              startIndex: 17 - pattern1Length - pattern2Length - pattern3Length, 
                                              number: secondPatternNr)
            return pattern4Length >= 5
        }
```

Some test patterns with results:

```
let match1 = match(binNrs: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]) // true
let match2 = match(binNrs: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) // false (4th sequence < 5)
let match3 = match(binNrs: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]) // false (1st sequence < 3)
let match4 = match(binNrs: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) // false (2nd sequence < 5)
```